# Tomcat - SSL certificate configure

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I want to setup SSL certificate on tomcat, specification of my server:

```
OS: ubuntu 18.04 LTS
tomcat: 9.0.31
java: 1.8.0_242
```

I have these files:

```
xyz.key
xyz.ca-bundle
xyz.crt
```

I want to run tomcat on port 443 although I Know I can change port by using `server.xml` file.

By using the above files I can easily setup ssl in apache, But my question is which type of file format I should have in order to setup ssl in tomcat server and if I need some other format then how should I convert these files ?

Comment: If you already have Apache it should speak plaintext to Tomcat, preferably AJP rather than HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Question is pretty unclear, but I assume what you're trying to do is run Tomcat standalone, not with Apache Httpd as a proxy. In that case, the easiest and best thing to do is to upgrade to a modern version of Java. Java 9 and later support PKCS12, which is easier than using JKS, so you should upgrade, either to 11 (the current LTS release) or 14 (current release).
Once that is done, you can use [this tool](https://github.com/chiralsoftware/CertWeb) to generate a CSR and save a key and help set up your configuration. It might be easier than doing this by editing files.